# An Irish monarchy and IRA

Tags: alternate-history, politics, military-organisation, royalty

I need a change in history so in the year 2020, Ireland is ruled by a Constitutional Monarchy. It is still a catholic nation (not celtic), has a democratically elected parliament and leaders, and the monarchy is respected by the Irish citizens... at least most of them.

Every other nation, along with their political relationships, should be as close to the present as possible. This also applies to the Irish Republican Army. It still exists as an armed organization. However, I want this organization to only use political means (not bombing or gun violence) to achieve the aim to turning Ireland into a republic. There would be some connection (unofficial channel of sorts) between the monarchy and the IRA. And the portion that is in North Ireland will have the same fate as its real life counterpart: fight, lose, and then truce alongside demilitarisation.

Comment: "What's the least amount of historical change to bring about X?" has been a long-standing question type on this Stack.

Comment: However, it appears you haven't done your research. After a quick read of the [Monarchy of Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchy_of_Ireland) we learn that had William the Conqueror and his pals left Ireland alone, there would have been a better-than-average chance Ireland would have remained a monarchy - although a fair amount of history would have had to change for England and the other surrounding nations to remain as they are and not absorb the Irish monarchy as they did in 1603. Go read that page and tell us why it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: (1) Ireland *was* a constitutional monarchy up to 1937. (2) There is no such thing as the "Ireland Republican Army". If you mean the *Irish* Republican Army, that organization has a [complicated history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Republican_Army). But since you exclude terrorism, then I don't see how your fictitious IRA is different from [Sinn Féin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinn_Féin). (3) During the looooong time while the Irish Crown was in personal union with the English Crown, there have been countless opportunities to make it work; just pick any one of them.

Comment: P.S. I somehow get the vague impression that you believe that the IRA still exists. It doesn't. IRA proper self-destructed in the 1960s. The most notable of the splinters was the [Provisional IRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provisional_Irish_Republican_Army) aka the Provos, who embarked on a prolonged terrorist campaign. The PIRA dissolved in 2006; there remained only tiny splinters, such as the tragi-comical [Real IRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Irish_Republican_Army). Finally, a new cartoon IRA may have been formed in the 2010s, or not -- you would need to ask an Irish person.

Comment: You really have two fundamentally opposed questions here. I think you're going to have to split this into a "Kingdom of Ireland" query and a "IRA between the IK and the UK". You really also need to clarify the nature of the Irish monarchy you're looking for. Whence does it stem? Is it a survival of the old pre-English hegemony native kingdoms? Is it split off from the UK (kind of like what happened to Hannover in the 1830s)? Is it a newly proclaimed kingdom based on the Westminster / UK system? As far as the IRA, you're going to have to help us by clarifying how that comes about from (cont)...

Comment: (cont) ... within a strongly monarchical Ireland. Especially if said Ireland has had to deal with an England similar to the one of history (absentee landlords, potato famines and the like). Also, I think you're really going to have to channel your inner blarney and tell us how you're going to get a load of Irishmen ***not to fight***. I'm going to VTC your query until you can sort out these issues! This is an interesting alt-history query! I hope you can edit it into two good queries that fit the forum!

Comment: @elemtilas If you add a native monarchist faction to the Irish Civil War, you get a king and *more* fighting.

Comment: @AlexP What you say is true of course but one can imagine that they came back for fictional purposes much like Hitler has in a hilarious satire. There were certainly other paras in Ireland on either side as well. But yes the IRA no longer exists and the other things are true too. 'Ireland Republican ..' was I guess a typo or something like that? What I'm trying to say is even if these things are true (as they are) it still could be fun to think about this other version though perhaps some who lived in the Troubles would not agree with that! BTW I also think the OP might think IRA still exists.

Comment: Some questions: 1) Do you want a British or homegrown monarchy? 2) Is the IRA still republican and socialist?

Comment: @SeanOConnor I want Irish homegrown monarchy. And the IRA is still republican and socialist, but no terror attack in Ireland. They only conduct terror attack in Northern Ireland before the truce with UK government.

Comment: Why not just write up your exposition? Isn't the only problem, how you might reconcile a 'homegrown monarchy' with any Republican movement? Of course there's a huge difference between home-grown and British monarchy but how could republicans go to bed with either?

Why would your republican and socialist IRA make terror attacks only in Northern Ireland?

Where did your 'truce with UK government' come from?

Again, why not just write up your exposition?

Comment: Where did this Irish Monarchy come from?
If Northern Ireland exists then presumably Ireland was part of the UK at some point. In your alternate history did Irish monarchs survive in exile or hidden in the country? Or did a new monarchy spring up circa 1921 when Ireland regained it's independence?
Either way I struggle to see where the IRA come into it, originally they were just the Irish army (technically rebels at the time). If the Ireland struggling for independence was a monarchy then they would have been the Royal Irish Army or similar instead.

Comment: @adaliabooks I want an independent Irish monarchy, different from the British one

Answer (score 4):

### The british army reformed early, and won WW1 faster.

When Britain had a war with Tibet in 1904, they incorrectly believed Russia was supplying Tibet with arms. In this alternate universe, Russia was supplying Tibet with arms. It was a brutal slog, which only succeeded when Britain learned to use indirect artillery fire and heavy machine gun fire. This led to army reforms. In WW1, a more effective British army defeated the Germans in 1917, before the USA got involved.

### The Irish war of independence failed.

In 1919 to 1921, Ireland fought and won a war of independence against a war weary Britain worried about American influence and unwilling to be extremely brutal. In this timeline, America stayed independent and the British public was much less war weary. The rebellion was brutally crushed, and most of the war eager rebels murdered.

### King Edward VIII fell in love with an Irish woman.

He was a very famously short lived king who fell in love with an American woman irl. In this world, he fell in love with an Irish woman. With the money of Britain increasingly depleted in the great depression, Britain decided on a compromise to stop the increasing chaos and expense of Ireland. A partitioned Ireland, with Edward VIII as king alongside his Irish wife.

This Irish woman was a member of the IRA. Forever more, the IRA and the monarchy would be entangled in a confusing mess of alliances and relationships.

Comment: This new girl will be more unpopular than Wallis Simpson and Meghan Markle combined. You might end up with Ireland as a monarchy and Britain as a republic!

Comment: *Unpopular in England

Comment: Edward's life was plenty long, but his reign was short

Answer (score 4):

**The British Monarchy becomes the Irish Monarchy.**

Ireland has not had its own monarchy for about a thousand years. The quickest way to get an Irish monarchy is to move the British Monarchy to Ireland.

Ireland never established its independence from Britain. Due to better treatment than in the real world, following the Act of Union there was no War of Independence.

Ireland remained an exclave of the British Empire. They worship the British Monarch.

Then one day England gets conquered. Perhaps during WW1 or WW2. The monarchy flees to Ireland. They become the kings and queens of Ireland and nowhere else.

**Edit:** Britain losing WW1 or WW2 is because they were stretched by pouring funds into Ireland to improve the quality of life for the locals, rather than enlisting their sons for a pittance to fight and die in their wars overseas. This is the same reason Ireland is happy to remain in the union. Because the locals see the benefits of staying in the Union.

I leave to your imagination what happens after the war. Perhaps Britain becomes a German speaking nation and is otherwise  similar but more efficient than real Britain. Perhaps the Allies retake Britain but culturally the monarchy never recovers.  They are resented for fleeing and abandoning their people. Perhaps Ireland then becomes independent and keeps its monarchy.

Comment: This is the answer I think takes the fewest liberties with reality. Had the Brits not been unholy a*holes when they stomped into Ireland and “subjugated” the people with such bloody enthusiasm there might have been a better relationship between the two today, up to and including the Irish state being a happy part of the UK. Bonus points if you assassinate that <profanity removed> Cromwell.

Comment: Was there anyone that King John didn't subjugate with bloody enthusiasm? Including his own people and even the nobility?

Comment: @Dúthomhas I suspect you can keep the historic subjugation, as long as you give the locals a better quality of life from Union onwards. It would be consistent with Britain losing one of their wars, if they are pumping more funds into Ireland rather than enlisting the local boys.

Comment: Britain becomes a socialist hellhouse - Welcome Kaiserreich!

Answer (score 3):

### The monarchy came about during the Civil War

This is tricky, because you'd need to establish an Irish monarchy after the formation of the IRA. I can't see there being much room between the British and the IRA for an Irish monarchist faction before or during or immediately after the War of Independence.

The best loophole is the Civil War, where Ireland is basically independent but the IRA is fractured.

Insert a monarchist faction that beats both of the real history factions (de Valera gets assassinated on the same day as Michael Collins, as do his cabinet members), or have de Valera or some near equivalent gain total control and declare themself king, followed by a transition to constitutional monarchy after he dies. With EdV as an absolute monarch, the Catholicism goes to the next level. Sinn Fein outlasts the IRA's military wing just like in real life.

Depending on the king's ancestry and politics, you have just made Ulster into Westeros; the Troubles now have royal families leading both sides. Dolores O'Riordan's biggest hit ends up having even more historically inspired emotional turmoil driving it. She still dies young.

Edit: The  IRA doesn't attack the Irish monarchy with arms in very much the same way Islamist groups don't attack Saudi Arabia. They would like to on paper, but the monarchy/army is ruthless and very good at quelling internal terrorism, while not giving a brass razzoo about what they do to the North.

Answer (score 1):

**Scotland setup / schemer Prince**

Ireland remains in the UK with a status similar to Scotland and North Ireland in our world.  Maybe other parts of the Empire (Canada, Australia) are also still part of the UK.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_monarchy

> The United Kingdom and the other Commonwealth realms are all
> constitutional monarchies in the Westminster system of constitutional
> governance.

The NRA in your world wants Irish home rule and independence and as you have taken away the historic violent aspects, functions like our world's Scottish [Home Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_rule) movement.  Other commonwealth members each have their own home rule movement; especially the Isle of Man which thinks it can become Grand Cayman.

The popular prince has considerable personal wealth and is a political actor to a greater degree than Prince Charles in our time.  He supports the home rule movement in all Commonwealth members, "devolved parliaments" and political independence for Ireland, Scotland and other commonwealth members except the Isle of Man.  This support is both public to the degree his public role tolerates and to a greater degree private.  If the NRA and prince get their way the role of the monarchy would not change; only the parliamentary aspects of the government would change.

Answer (score 1):

"This also applies to the Irish Republican Army. It still exists as an armed organization. However, I want this organization to only use political means (not bombing or gun violence)"

This I think answers the question. The IRA never promotes armed revolution so never  Becomes popular enough to rebel against Britain.

Instead monarchist faction that  Advocates for armed revolution becomes popular among the people. Then it just takes the place of the Ira in are time line.

Meanwhile the original Ira Continues to use activism And political means only  After the revolution they use it  Against the Irish monarchy instead of the English monarchy.

Answer (score 1):

**No Norman Invasion!**

It seems hard to believe that the Irish independence movement from starting with 1798 rebellion could bring about an Irish monarchy as they were strongly republican, as were most movements since then.

However, if you go back in time to the Norman invasion, Ireland had a number of kings, including a high king. The king of Leinster was ousted from power after he kidnapping the wife of the king of Breifne, so he ran off to look for help from the Normans to get his land back, which is what triggered the Norman invasion of Ireland.

Take that away and you've now got a completely different Irish history, but with kings and queens.

So there are still a number of things to explain, but history being so different, you can now make up what you like, for example:

A strong king came to power from the O'Brien family in Munster and became the high king, and managed to mostly unite Ireland as a single and strong entity, helped by being descended from Brian Boru. They had strong enough personality and were diplomatically skilled enough to somehow or another ensure that England didn't invade anyway in the following centuries.

However, the McLoughlins and O'Neills of Ulster never *really* warmed to this dynasty from the South, and eventually, after the time of Henry VIII started making deals with Protestant English rulers in exchange for help resisting the O'Briens.

So the North began filling up with Protestants loyal to Britain as it did in real life, and that is why we still have the strife now. But by the time this happened the people who came over weren't as motivated as Strongbow and Ireland was more united which is why there wasn't a large invasion like the Normans did IRL.